# SSH Shell in Canada for SSHTunnel/Socks proxy testing

Tags: shell, proxy, ssh, socks, ssh-tunnel

i've been using ec2 to crate ssh tunnels to test the rendering of our site from different geographical regions. I now need a node in canada - which ec2 doesn't support. Are there any well known (preferably free) SSH Shell providers in canada i could use for this?
thanks

rich

Answer (score 0):

Canada is a very big place.

People in Vancouver will get similar results to US west coast, those in Toronto or Montreal will get east coast results, and geoip will often kick in and clock or enable content for anywhere in Canada.

Answer (score 0):

You could try OVH.ca.  They're a French company, and have a big data centre on the outskirts of Montreal, Quebec, in a city called BHS (Beauharnois, QC).

They generally have cheap dedicated servers, starting at 29 CAD/month; be advised that BHS only seems to have one big fibre pipe running into it, which gets damaged every now and then, and during the time that it's damaged, the most you'd be getting from them is something along the lines of 10kbps or less.  Otherwise, I have no problem getting 200'000 kbps (and above) from them.